# opecv Aruco markers pose estimation

Tags: opencv3.0, pose-estimation, aruco

I am trying to use aruco markers and estimating the pose of single markers. Sometimes I get weirdly large values as

```
Marker ID 2 : [-1.11133e+06, -918896, 3.3727e+06] , [-3.22862e+08, 4.49601e+08, -5.05835e+08]
```

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: another example of wrong pose values : Marker ID 2 : [-8.65644, -6.67415, 30.2641] , [259.038, 323.428, 243.847]

Answer (score 0):

Setting useExtrinsicGuess flag to *true* caused this problem. Now I am using SolvePnP directly with CV_ITERATIVE. The pose values are not super stable and consistent but still better than before. There is still an occasional  Z axis flipping.